# music API - Use in application as samples

Tags: api, spotify, sample

I'm currently searching for a music streaming service which allows me
to stream music to mobile phone apps. This will be both the Apple
iPhone and any Android phone. The intention is that users of the app
can listen shortly to some music and then they can carry on with our
game.

Is this possible with your service? If so, what is the cost in terms of
licensing and copyrights? Is there any restriction with regards to
countries?

Best regards,

Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, libSpotify allows streaming of music to mobile phones. Users need to have a Spotify Premium account to allow this, though, and you can only create Spotify accounts in a limited number of countries.

The terms of use for the libSpotify service can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/terms-of-use-us/).